# android mediaplayer auto restart

Tags: java, android

How can i make mediaplayer auto restart after the sound has finished

this is my code: it plays the music then just stops after it finished i want it to replay after it stops

```
           MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(main.this, R.raw.ngmusic);
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try to use this one ?

```
mediaPlayer.setLooping( true );
```